# Mongrel server trying to perform GET on 127.0.0.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localhost, mongrel

I've recently started a Rails 3 project which I checked out from github. The application uses subdomains to access accounts so I had to perform a small change in my etc/hosts/ file so that the app navigates properly. I'm now trying to login to the app but am seeing a very strange request in the terminal:

```
Started GET "/session/new" for 127.0.0.1 at Sun May 08 13:48:38
```

I'm using the mongrel server and its running on ip `0.0.0.0` so I can't figure out why the app is looking up `127.0.0.1`. I'm on OS X so ive stopped my local apache server too.

I've removed all traces of the string `"127.0.0.1"` in my app but still see the request being made to that IP.

Does anyone have any idea's as to why this is happening?

EDIT: Hosts file is as following:

```
##
# Host Database 
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost ger.mpt.local
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
#::1             localhost 
#fe80::1%lo0        localhost
```

EDIT: I should also mention that I get a 302 redirect status from firebug when I submit the login form.

Thanks,
gearoid

Comment: What url do you type in the browser?

Comment: "gearoid.myapp.local" which in the etc/hosts file resolves to ip 0.0.0.0

Comment: This is Ok, you should not worry about that, 0.0.0.0 means listen on all interfaces, 127.0.0.1 is default IP of the loopback interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this lay in the session storage configuration.

After debugging through the code I could see that the session wasn't being made readily available to various authentication methods. Upon deeper inspection I found a config file which set the domain which the session is picked up from. Setting that to "mpt.local" allowed the session to get picked up and thus allowed me to login.

Answer (score 1):

Mmm. `0.0.0.0` means that Mongrel listens on every IP address "associated" with your system, including `localhost` (`localhost` is defined as an alias to `127.0.0.1` everywhere).

Comment: If I try to run it on a different ip (using rails server -b 127.0.0.10) I get the following error: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel/tcphack.rb:12:in `initialize_without_backlog': Can't assign requested address - bind(2) (Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL)

Comment: For sure, because your system cannot "resolve" (`bind` method works only on local addresses), for example, `127.0.0.10`, Mongrel cannot bind its socket to that address.

Comment: So how come I can't bind it to 127.0.0.1 which is a local address?

Comment: Show your `/etc/hosts` file, please.

Comment: You do not have `127.0.0.1` in your hosts file, so `bind` method cannot use it. You could at least uncomment the `127.0.0.1      localhost` line to make it work.

Comment: If I uncomment that line then I can bind mongrel to the ip. However, when I try to login, I'm still not getting directed properly. The response retruned in firebug reads as "Failed to load source for: http://ger.mpt.local:3000/session"

Comment: Associate it with `127.0.0.1`, too, with something like `127.0.0.1 localhost ger.mpt.local`.

Comment: Just tried that without any joy im afraid. I get a 302 status when I submit the form - maybe this has something to do with it?

Comment: That 302 status could suggest that everything works. More information is needed to make any future decisions.

Comment: I'll gladly provide you with such info (and some reputation points) if you can help me out!

Comment: It is ok, there is no interface with 0.0.0.0 assigned to it, so your browser redirected to default IP of loopback.